# How to serialize List<(string,string,string)> with System.Text.Json in C#

Tags: c#, serialization, system.text.json

I'm trying for the first time to make a report using a data class that will be serialized to JSON instead of doing it manually. The heart of my data is a list declared like this

`public List<(string oid,string data,string desc)> assetData { get; set; }`

My Serialize function is

```
        private static void Serialize(Asset asset, JsonSerializerOptions? options = null)
        {
            var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize<Asset>(
                asset,
                options ?? new JsonSerializerOptions() { 
                    WriteIndented = true,
                    IgnoreNullValues = true,
                });
            Console.WriteLine(json);

        }
```

The Json serializer will just give me empty {} for each line, how do I make it so that it gives me the name of the field and the data in an orderly fashion?

My data looks like this

```
OID= 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0 Translation= BGP4-V2-MIB::bgpM2BaseNotifications Data= 
OID= 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.2.0 Translation= CABH-IETF-CAP-MIB::cabhCapNotification Data= 1.3.6.1.4.1.8691.10.2210
OID= 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0 Translation= DISMAN-EVENT-MIB::sysUpTimeInstance Data= 01:39:31.4500000
OID= 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.4.0 Translation= SNMPv2-MIB::sysContact.0 Data= 
OID= 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0 Translation= SNMPv2-MIB::sysName.0 Data= E2210_6115
OID= 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.6.0 Translation= SNMPv2-MIB::sysLocation.0 Data= 
OID= 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.7.0 Translation= SNMPv2-MIB::sysServices.0 Data= 72
OID= 1.3.6.1.2.1.2.1.0 Translation= RFC-1213-MIB::ifNumber.0 Data= 2
OID= 1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.1.1 Translation= RFC-1213-MIB::ifIndex.1 Data= 1
OID= 1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.1.2 Translation= RFC-1213-MIB::ifIndex.2 Data= 2
OID= 1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2.1 Translation= RFC-1213-MIB::ifDescr.1 Data= Moxa Ethernet port 01
OID= 1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2.2 Translation= RFC-1213-MIB::ifDescr.2 Data= Moxa serial port 01
```

[image: My list in VS]

Comment: Please share a [mcve]. Populate the data _in code_.

Comment: [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) does the right thing. Can you not use that?

Answer (score 2):

The solution to this was to make a custom JsonConverter class.

```
public class ListConverter : JsonConverter<List<(string,string,string)>>
    {
        public override List<(string, string, string)> Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, List<(string, string, string)> value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        {

            writer.WriteStartArray("dataArray");

            foreach (var line in value)
            {
                writer.WriteStartObject();
                writer.WriteStartObject("Oid");
                writer.WriteStringValue(line.Item1);
                writer.WriteEndObject();
                writer.WriteStartObject("Data");
                writer.WriteStringValue(line.Item2);
                writer.WriteEndObject();
                writer.WriteStartObject("Desc");
                writer.WriteStringValue(line.Item3);
                writer.WriteEndObject();
                writer.WriteEndObject();



            }
            writer.WriteEndArray();
        }

    }
```

It results in JSON like this

```
 "dataArray": [
    {
      "Oid": {
        "1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0"
      },
      "Data": {
        ""
      },
      "Desc": {
        "BGP4-V2-MIB::bgpM2BaseNotifications"
      }
    },
    {
      "Oid": {
        "1.3.6.1.2.1.1.2.0"
      },
      "Data": {
        "1.3.6.1.4.1.8691.10.2210"
      },
      "Desc": {
        "CABH-IETF-CAP-MIB::cabhCapNotification"
      }
    },
    {
      "Oid": {
        "1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0"
      },
      "Data": {
        "05:42:39.6300000"
      },
      "Desc": {
        "DISMAN-EVENT-MIB::sysUpTimeInstance"
      }
    },
    {
      "Oid": {
        "1.3.6.1.2.1.1.4.0"
      },
      "Data": {
        ""
      },
      "Desc": {
        "SNMPv2-MIB::sysContact.0"
      }
    },
    {
      "Oid": {
        "1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0"
      },
      "Data": {
        "E2210_6115"
      },
      "Desc": {
        "SNMPv2-MIB::sysName.0"
      }
    },
....
```

It probably has room for improvements, but now I know how to do this for the future.

Answer (score 1):

Tuple works like field (not property). By default, field are ignored by serializer.

You need enable [JsonSerializerOptions.IncludeFields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializeroptions.includefields?view=net-5.0#System_Text_Json_JsonSerializerOptions_IncludeFields) :

```cs
private static void Serialize(Asset asset, JsonSerializerOptions? options = null)
{
    var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize<Asset>(
        asset,
        options ?? new JsonSerializerOptions {
            WriteIndented = true,
            IgnoreNullValues = true,
            IncludeFields = true
        }
    );
    Console.WriteLine(json);
}
```

Comment: I actually did try that, but I get that 'JsonSerializerOptions' does not contain a definition for 'IncludeFields'. I wanted to manually define which fields would be serialized. I'm using Sytem.Text.Json 5.0.0. After some research I see that Include fields
Fields are not supported in System.Text.Json in .NET Core 3.1. Custom converters can provide this functionality.

Comment: What .NET do you target?

Comment: .Net Core 3.1, I should have mentioned.